# How long does it to sort 2.5 million numbers using HeapSort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I have 2.5 million entries/numbers, which I am using HeapSort to sort them by inserting in a sorted heap. But it is taking for ever.. I know heapsort running time is O(nlogn) but in real life, on a basic computer, how much time are we talking about here? I have 8 G.B. of RAM on my Windows machine, but I have dual-booted Ubuntu which I believe is chosen to run with 1 G.B of RAM.

It took less than 15 seconds for 15,000 numbers. so proportionally speaking, will it take about 40 minutes?

Comment: Your question can't be answered without exact knowledge of runtime language, elements type (well, numbers can be flat memory cells or boxed in objects), compare function, etc., and resulting coefficient may vary in many hundred times. Please specify more details. OTOH I guess 15 seconds for 15000 numbers is definitely too high even if each number is separate object in Visual Basic:) so something is wrong in your algorithm or setup.

Comment: That's not the best way to heap sort, but it's hard to know what your alternatives since you don't even mention which language you're using. Normally to heapsort you would use something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap (which is fast) and then remove the elements in order one at a time. (If you always put the removed element at the end of the heap, which becomes one shorter with every removal, then you end up with a sorted vector.)

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: From a purely mathematical standpoint and all other things being equal, you're looking at about 65 minutes to process 2.5 million numbers, if processing 15,000 numbers takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Sorting 2.5 million elements using heapsort should take ... like a second (or maybe a few). There's probably something seriously wrong with your algorithm if sorting a mere 15k takes 15 seconds.

Comment: 2^14=16384 > 15000 so n log n (15 000) < 210 000 and making this many comparisons should take a lot less than 15 seconds on a machine with a GHz clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a rough estimate, assuming no additional memory related overhead when scaling from 15k to 2.5 million, the runtime will be:
  (2.5m * log(2.5m)) / (1.5k * log(1.5k)) * 15 seconds = **64 minutes**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about heap sort and my eyes pop out when I'm looking at the original asker sorting 15 seconds for 15,000 numbers, or the accepted answer that accounts for that, but the default C++ STL sort of a vector of 2.5M integers takes me < 100ms. Compiled with -O3, of course, if not: < 700ms.